# split UL into multiple ULs at specified LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an LI element containing a single nested UL that will have 20-30 LIs, and some of the LIs will have child ULs. Right now it is one long scrolling list. I want to be able, via jQuery, to split the UL into three ULs, by passing a set of unique LI selectors (e.g., "li#item-173,li#item-169,li#item-175") to indicate the point at which a new UL should start.

So, instead of having a parent LI with a child UL of ~30 items. I want to have a parent LI with a child DIV, and inside of that DIV, three ULs with a various number of items, based on the "split points" I provide.

Hope this makes sense.

To see what I am trying to achieve...

The monolithic list can be seen by selecting the Industries & Resources menu item at the following link:

http://new.efigroupllc.com

Here is what I want to achieve, but will need to do it via jQuery on DOM ready, because the menu list is generated on the fly by the CMS serving the site. (Again, select the Industries & Resources menu item):

http://new.efigroupllc.com/biglist.html

Here is the current state of my code...

My problem is iterating over the LI elements in the container UL with the **each** method.

Below is as far as I got with the code before posting this edit. Guess it would have helped to post it. :-/

The "myCount" tells me there are 22 items (e.g., the length attribute). However, the alert within my "each" function only fires on the first element, and not for each of the 22 elements. Since I couldn't get the loop working the way I wanted, I never made it to the point of actually removing/appending LIs from the first UL to either the second or third UL.

Here is the code as of "this moment", however I am still puzzling through it.

```
var targetId = 'item-7';
var col2startId = 'item-168';
var col3startId = 'item-174';
// get all of the wrapper pieces in place!
// -- add wrapper
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' > ul').wrap('<div class="industries-list-wrapper">');
// -- add ULs and assign IDs!
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' div.industries-list-wrapper > ul').attr('id',targetId + 'col1');
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' div.industries-list-wrapper').append('<ul id="' + targetId + 'col2">');
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' div.industries-list-wrapper').append('<ul id="' + targetId + 'col3">');
// iterate over the source ULs LI elements, move LI element to columns as appropriate
var thisColumn = 1;
var myCount = jQuery('ul#'+targetId+'col1 > li').length;
alert('there are ' + myCount + ' LIs in the list!');
jQuery('ul#'+targetId+'col1 > li').each(
    function() {
        // check for trigger's to set column
        myCurrentId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        alert('myCurrentId = ' + myCurrentId);      
        if (jQuery(this).attr('id') == col2startId) {
            thisColumn = 2;
            alert('starting column 2!');
        } else if (jQuery(this).attr('id') == col3StartId) {
            thisColumn = 3;
            alert('starting column 3!');
        }
        if (thisColumn == 2) {
        // append jQuery(this) to column 2 and remove from column 1
        } else if (thisColumn == 3) {
        // append jQuery(this) to column 3 and remove from column 1
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Post your HTML and the JavaScript you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I am using the index number for this, so if you add new list item to the biglist you also have to change the indexes. heres the code -

```
var $div = $('div.industries-list-wrapper');
var $ul1 = $div.find('ul').first();
$ul1.attr('style', 'float:left;');

var $lis = $ul1.children('li');
console.log($lis);
var $ul3 = $('<ul style="float:left;"></ul>');
for (i = 21; i > 13; i--) {
    $ul3.prepend($lis[i]);
}
var $ul2 = $('<ul style="float:left;"></ul>');
for (i = 13; i > 8; i--) {
    $ul2.prepend($lis[i]);
}
$div.append($ul2);
$div.append($ul3);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pqzNB/)</kbd>

**update:**
`$` is not available in wordpres. so you have to use `jQuery`. the modified code is -

```
var $div = jQuery('<div class="industries-list-wrapper"/>');
var $pli = jQuery('a[href="/industries.html"]').closest('li');
var $ul1 = jQuery('a[href="/industries.html"]').next('ul');
$ul1.attr('style','float:left;');
var $lis = $ul1.children('li');
var $ul3 = jQuery('<ul style="float:left;"></ul>');
for (i = 21; i > 13; i--) {
    $ul3.prepend($lis[i]);
}
var $ul2 = jQuery('<ul style="float:left;"></ul>');
for (i = 13; i > 7; i--) {
    $ul2.prepend($lis[i]);
}
$div.append($ul1);
$div.append($ul2);
$div.append($ul3);
$pli.append($div);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. What I was having a problem with is iterating over the LI elements in the container UL.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Sometimes I complicate the living heck out of something before realizing that there is a very elegant solution. After experimenting further, I found that the *slice* method gave me precisely what I needed. Here is what I ended up doing...

```
var targetId = 'item-7';
var col2startIdx = 8;
var col3startIdx = 14;

// get all of the wrapper pieces in place!
// -- add wrapper
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' > ul').wrap('<div class="industries-list-wrapper">');

// -- add ULs and assign IDs!
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' div.industries-list-wrapper > ul').attr('id',targetId + '-col1');
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' div.industries-list-wrapper').append('<ul id="' + targetId + '-col2">');
jQuery('li#' + targetId + ' div.industries-list-wrapper').append('<ul id="' + targetId + '-col3">');

// -- slice up col1 into col2 and col3
// -- did the last column first, to make it easier for specifying an index value
jQuery('ul#'+targetId+'-col1 > li').slice(col3startIdx).appendTo('ul#'+targetId+'-col3');
jQuery('ul#'+targetId+'-col1 > li').slice(col2startIdx).appendTo('ul#'+targetId+'-col2');
```